Minimality of the Koszul resolution
Let $R = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $V = \mathbb{C}x\oplus\mathbb{C}y$. Then, the Koszul resolution of $R$ (as an $R$-bimodule) is given by
\begin{align*}
0\to R\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}\wedge^2V\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} R& \xrightarrow{\partial_2} R\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}V\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} R \xrightarrow{\partial_1} R\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} R \xrightarrow{\mathrm{mult}} R \to 0\,,\\
\partial_1(1\otimes v\otimes 1) &= 1\otimes v - v\otimes 1\,,\\
\partial_2(1\otimes x\wedge y\otimes 1) &= 1\otimes x\otimes y + x\otimes y\otimes1 - 1\otimes y\otimes x - y\otimes x\otimes 1\,.
\end{align*}
I want to know whether this resolution is minimal (i.e. each step is a projective cover). How can I (dis)prove this?
Since $R$ is not an Artinian ring, I'm not sure even a minimal resolution exists. Nonetheless, it seems somewhat plausible.
Any comments or references on other general results are appreciated.

Unless I'm missing something very subtle in your question, graded Nakayama lemma says that epimorphism between finitely generated modules over a connected graded algebra with 0th degree = base field is superfluous iff it is iso modulo maximal ideal. Hence projective covers exist.

Sorry, but it's not clear to me. If $f:M\to N$ is an epimorphism of graded f.g. modules and an iso modulo the maximal ideal, $\mathrm{Ker}f + H = M$ implies $H=M$ for a graded submodule $H$ by graded Nakayama's Lemma, but I'm not sure for a general submodule $H$. Am I missing something?

In the category of ungraded bimodules, the multiplication map $R\otimes_\mathbb{C}R\to R$ is not a projective cover. For example, the proper sub-bimodule of $R\otimes_\mathbb{C}R$ generated by $1\otimes1+x\otimes1-1\otimes x$ surjects onto $R$.
